# How to extract data from the physics engine

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I would to simulate the grasping of a hand and then to extract data such as :coordinates of points of contact, force applied by the model on the gresped object in those points, and deformations af the grasped object.
Does anybody know if it is possible and how to do it?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45175/how-to-extract-data-from-the-physics-engine/) by [tommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3100/tommy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2012-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Getting contact points and forces probably is possible. However, ODE, the physics engine that is used by Gazebo does not simulate deformations.

For getting forces, you can use gazebo's GetModelState service. For contact points, I guess you will have to write a gazebo plugin that has direct access to the physics engine.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5